# Why are there two versions of VLC on the Software Center?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, vlc

On the Software Center I've seen that there are two versions of VLC. The first one is the 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4, the one that I already have installed, and that has all the reviews on the page, and the second one is the  3.0.1-4-g14a4897.

Why? And should I uninstall the old one and switch to the other one, or not?